# Removing Epoxy Glue from a ceramic piezostack

Tags: solvents

I am going to stick a strain gauge to the side of an expanding piezocrystal using a basic 2 part epoxy glue. I am eventually also going to be sticking other things to it. Does anyone know a safe way to remove the glue without damaging the piezostack? The manual says specifically not to use acetone.